# F# Tuple Pattern Matching Question

Tags: f#, design-patterns, matching, tuples

Is there a way to pattern match in F# so that it will check to see if both elements in a two element tuples are equal. I'm incredibly new to F#, and also new to the whole concept of Pattern Matching in general. I was thinking something along the lines of...

```
let rec funct = function
    |(xs, xs) -> 0
    etc. etc. etc.
```

But I guess that would be too easy hah. Any suggestions? Or is there even a way to do that? Thanks for your help, you guys are incredibly helpful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
match e with    
| x,y when x = y -> ...
...
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233242.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125.aspx

Comment: Ah, the when keyword...Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Brian's answer is correct, but since you also asked about other ways I'll add an alternative - I don't usually use `match` to work with tuples because simple decomposition will always succeed (unless you use some complicated patterns or `when`). When writing a function, I would likely write:

```
let funct (x, y) = 
  if x = y then ...
  else ...
```

(But of course, it depends on the context - the `if` is probably good for small functions)